# For lotus notes accepted meetings, change the automatically set alarm notification timing

Tags: notifications, lotus-notes

In Lotus notes how to set for all accepted meeting request to have the notification to be set. Now for each I need to set.
Also when i set the default time is 30 min prior, how can I change it to be say 15 min for all notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Just goto `More - Preferences` (Tools - Preferences in older versions) action bar button or to `File - Preferences - Mail` in Versions > 8 and open the calendar preferences tab. There you will find the alarm settings for every type of calendar entries in one of the sub- tabs.